# Loading templates in DIV

Tags: jquery, html, templates

I have two divs and i want to load the templates over there. i'm trying to load like this,
its not working. here is my code.

Main.htm

```
Details

 <div id="placeholder1" />
 <div id="placeholder2" />
```

Template1.htm

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#example').dataTable({
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "sAjaxSource": '/Home/GetReport1',


                });
            });
        </script>

 </head>

TESTING.........

    <div id="dynamic">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="20%">Date</th>
                <th width="25%">Time</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
       </tbody>

    </table>
    </div>
    </html>
```

Template2.htm

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#example').dataTable({
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "sAjaxSource": '/Home/GetReport1',


                });
            });
        </script>

 </head>

TESTING.........

    <div id="dynamic">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="20%">Place</th>
                <th width="25%">Food</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
       </tbody>

    </table>
    </div>
    </html>
```

Here how i'm loading the template form JS file

myjs.js

```
 var placeholder = $("#tab");
            placeholder.setTemplateURL("/Templates/Home/main.htm");

            placeholder.load("/Templates/Home/pricinghistory.htm");

            var firstDiv = $("placeholder1");

            firstDiv.setTemplate("/Templates/Home/Template1.htm");

            firstDiv.load("/Templates/Home/Template1.htm");
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your templates you seem to be using the `dataTable` plugin you have never included its corresponding script file. Also you seem to be using jQuery but I cannot see any reference to it neither. So make sure that you have included the scripts that you intend to use in your templates:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Also in order to debug those kind of problems I would more than strongly recommend you start using a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug. It would show you potential javascript errors you may have, you will be able to see exact requests/responses from your AJAX calls and immediately see potential reasons for them failing and much more.

Comment: Darin, thanks for ur reply. Yes i m loading them in site.master file. But atleast it should show "testing.... string" right? its not even showing that also

Comment: I think you are getting what i'm trying to say, i dont want grid. But atleast the testing string should come na, its not even appearing

Comment: Then I guess you have some issue with loading the templates. Check your javascript console, check the AJAX request in FireBug to see why is it failing.

Comment: ok, i m installing firebug, i will check.. thanks, but do u think anything wrong in loading the technique wat i m using?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Json format of the data returning from ajax source, It should include 'aaData'.also try to trouble shoot the template pages whether or not template pages getting the data using datatable, later try to load into div's present in Main.html